# Tables: from Word to LaTeX

Tags: tables

This question may have been asked in the past, but the answers do not satisfy me.
Here is the thing. I have prepared a statistical table in Word, with stars indicating the significance level and the standard errors are under the coefficients in parentheses.

I have the macro called `excel2latex` and I know how to make it work so I can obtain the TeX tables. The point is that, when I copy and paste the table (which is ready) from Word into excel, the parentheses are gone. I do not want this to happen, for I have to do the job once again.

Is there any macro for word that can produce TeX tables like the one in Excel?

The problem in simple terms:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
From Word something like this 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline var & 0.045*** \\ 
\hline  & (0.005) \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

when copied in Excel becomes this monstrosity where the standard error appears to be negative:

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline var & 0.045*** \\ 
\hline  & -0.005 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are many ways to create a table in Excel, not just one. Without more information about the look and feel of your table, it's not going to be straightforward to provide advice.

Comment: @Mico can you be more precise? As I said the table in Word is ready. The problem is that during the copy-paste procedure, the format from Word is not maintained.

Comment: You can save from Word in many formats - e.g. html, rtf, ... perhaps one of these is easier to transform to TeX, perhaps with pandoc (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

Comment: Is this a question about conversion from Word to Excel, with LaTeX used to describe the problem? If so, this question might be better suited for [su].

Comment: @doncherry No, I have tables in Word that I want to make them in LaTeX format, but as it is easier to make tables in Word or Excel, I prepared them there first, and now I want to have them made in TeX so I can use them in my thesis, which is written in TeX.

Comment: I will provide a partial solution to this problem. It seems that something that is of this format for example in Word, (1234), when pasted in Excel it becomes: -1234. Hence one can use brackets, that is [1234] and the format will be kept in Excel.

Comment: This seems off-topic since the problem exists between Word and Excel.  I bet Excel or Word is set up by default to have some sort of markup where things in parentheses "means" negative numbers; this can probably be disabled.  Or export the table as a `.csv` and then import it..?

Comment: @jon Yeah, I think this is the case. Now, I will use Excel with brackets instead of () and I will be fine.

Comment: If Excel continues to interpret parenthesized numbers as negative, one solution is to remove the parentheses in Word, bring the table into Excel, and then apply a custom numeric format to the standard error cells. The custom format would be `(0.000)`, which would give a three-decimal number with literal parentheses before and after.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your Excel is set up to treat numbers in parenthesis as negative numbers. There is probably  a setting to disable this.  But that is a question for another site.

However, you can fix this in LaTeX by using [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) to automate the conversion of negative numbers to instead use parenthesis as seen in the second table.  If the content begins with a `-` and ends with a `*` we don't put the parenthesis, but do insert a negative sign in math mode.

[image]

### Notes:

- I used [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) to see if the string begins with a `-`, in which case the `-` is removed and the *entire* quantity surrounded by parenthesis.  This can probably be down without this package if needed.
- For the case where the text begins with an `-` and ends with an `*`, I used `$-$\StrBehind{#1}{-}` instead of just `$#1$` as the later resulted in extra spacing within the `*`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\MyNumberFormatter}[1]{%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{-}{%    This begins with a negative sign
        \IfEndWith{#1}{*}{%  Ends with a * so it is a coefficient.
            $-$\StrBehind{#1}{-}%
        }{%
            (\StrBehind{#1}{-})%
        }%
    }{%
        #1%
    }%
}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\MyNumberFormatter}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
From Word something like this 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline var & 0.045*** \\ 
\hline  & (0.005) \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

when copied in Excel becomes this monstrosity where the standard error appears to be negative:

\begin{tabular}{|c|C|}
\hline var & 0.045*** \\ 
\hline  & -0.005 \\ 
\hline   & -0.045*** \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir, I do appreciate your help. I have to say something though. The parentheses must go only to the standard errors and not the coefficients. That said, if I have a coefficient like -0.340** I do not want it to be (0.340). For now, I will use brackets [], instead of (). Then in the TeX editor I will replace [] with ().

Comment: @PantelisKazakis: Have updated solution to not put `()` if the text ends with a `*`.  Also, no needs for formalities with the `Sir` :-)

Comment: Peter, a coefficient need not have `*` sign when it is not statistically significant. We use asterisks to just indicate significance, e.g., `***` for 1%, `**` for 5%, and `*` for 10%.

Comment: @PantelisKazakis: I am still not sure I fully understand the algorithm to determine if you want the `()` or not. But, I hope the above can be modified to suit you needs.  If you provide a complete test case and the expected results I can try to have a look at it.